# Automatically run rfkill unblock on startup

Tags: wifi, startup

I'm running Elementary OS on an old(er) HP Pavilion dm1. Unfortunately, on startup my wireless is hard disabled, and I need to run `sudo rfkill unblock all` to get it up and running. Works fine once I do though.

Is there any way to either:
1) Automatically run this line with startup
2) Not need to do this anymore?

When I use rfkill to view any blocks, there's a hard block on the wireless, and the wireless button's light is orange. Pressing the button does nothing. After running the line, I can switch wireless on and off at will.

Comment: It's reproducible on other distros?

Comment: I think it is better to use the path: /usr/sbin/rfkill unblock all because there may be permission problems when executing the script.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach to unblocking the Wi-Fi interface on boot is to modify the kernel boot parameters (via grub/bootloader config or on a Raspberry Pi in the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file), and add these two parameters on the end of the line:

```
systemd.restore_state=0 rfkill.default_state=1
```

The first one disables the systemd rfkill restore service, whilst the second sets the default kernel rfkill status to enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

- You can add the command `rfkill unblock all` using "System Settings > Startup Applications > Add"
- Or add it to your /etc/rc.local file, before any `return` statement:

  ```
  rfkill unblock all
  ```
- Not sure of this one; you can create a script (`unblock.sh`) in `/etc/init.d` with the single line `rfkill unblock all >&2`. Then, run `chmod +x unblock.sh`

Comment: Adding `rfkill unblock all` to `/etc/rc.local` didn't work for me on Debian 4.1.3.1 (it's soft disabled by default)

Comment: I have the same issue, soft-disabled by default, on Linux Mint 17.2 . Which is based on Ubuntu (which is based on Debian). A hassle to manage to enable wlan by default. I tried `rc.local`, service in `init.d`, ... that does work few seconds then *something* get it blocked

Answer (score 1):

If you are using systemd, you can do this by running (as root or with sudo):

```
systemctl enable rfkill-unblock@all
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to manage `rfkill` status on boot is [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/introduction.html) (*"TLP is a feature-rich command line utility for Linux, saving laptop battery power without the need to delve deeper into technical details."*).

The specific setting in `/etc/tlp.conf` is:

```
DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi"
```

(See [Radio Device Switching](https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/radio.html).)